# How to order by COUNT with SUM and MINUS of multi tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show post by order them with sum of comment and like.
There are three table using in this query **post**,**comment** and **like** 
for table like it has column **type** that keep value **like** or **unlike**.

**SQL**

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) AS count_comment 
FROM comment WHERE comment.post_id = post.post_id),
       (SELECT COUNT(id) AS count_like 
FROM like WHERE like.post_id = post.post_id AND like.type = 'like'),
       (SELECT COUNT(id) AS count_unlike 
FROM like WHERE like.post_id = post.post_id AND like.type = 'unlike'),
       post.* FROM post
       ORDER BY (count_comment + count_like - count_unlike) DESC;
```

So, this is an example when it shows on the page

```
post_id | comment | like | unlike | (comment+like-unlike)
4       | 5       | 3    | 1      |  7
1       | 2       | 3    | 0      |  5 
2       | 1       | 1    | 4      | -2 
...     | ...     | ...  | ...    | ...
```

My problem is my SQL is very slow, please suggest another way if it can. I've tried to use JOIN but i can't figured out how its SQL should be, please help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a derived table for each of the counts, the query below counts comments, likes, unlikes for each post and then joins the counts to the `post` table by `post_id`.

```
SELECT 
    p.post_id,
    COALESCE(c.comment_count,0) comment_count,
    COALESCE(l.like_count,0) like_count,
    COALESCE(ul.unlike_count,0) unlike_count,
    (COALESCE(c.comment_count,0) 
       + COALESCE(l.like_count,0) 
       - COALESCE(ul.unlike_count,0)) total
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.post_id,
    COUNT(*) comment_count
    FROM comment c
    GROUP BY c.post_id
) c ON c.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT l.post_id,
    COUNT(*) like_count
    FROM like l
    WHERE l.type = 'like'
    GROUP BY l.post_id
) l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ul.post_id,
    COUNT(*) unlike_count
    FROM like ul
    WHERE ul.type = 'unlike'
    GROUP BY ul.post_id
) ul ON ul.post_id = p.post_id
ORDER BY total DESC
```